# How to activate a script from another object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to activate a script from another object on a button press. Heres what I tried:

```
function Update () {
if(Input.touchCount == 1) {
GameObject.Find("theobject").GetComponent(thescript).enabled = true
}
else {
GameObject.Find("theobject").GetComponent(thescript).enabled = false
} 
}
```

When I press play, It has no errors but when I press the button, nothing happens. Are there anything wrong with the script. I'm new to Unity and Javascript. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,10,100,90),"Button to activate object"))
{
gameObject.active = true;
}
```

Comment: does that access the other gameobject? The script is attached to the other object i want it to activate it on