# How to enable a script from another object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to play another script on another object when I press a GUI texture which I already have.

I tried `GameObject.Find(theobject).GetComponent(thescript).enabled = true` but it didn't work. I didn't get any errors. It's just when I press the GUI texture it doesn't do anything(by the way I have the function `OnMouseDown()` on the GUI texture)

Can anyone help me? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: The script for the button is:

```
function OnMouseDown () {
GameObject.Find("TheObject").GetComponent(thescriptwithoutthespeachmarks).enabled = true
}
```

Comment: can you include your script here?

Comment: You don't have a semicolon closing your line; is that just a copy&paste error?

Comment: that was a copy and paste error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to activate a script from another object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836184/how-to-activate-a-script-from-another-object)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `Update()` function:

```
if(GUITexture.Contains(Input.MousePosition)){
  if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
    GameObject.Find("TheObject").GetComponent(thescriptwithoutthespeachmarks).enabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. error : contains is not a member of the gui texture

Comment: Try this one: `if(GUITexture.HitTest(Input.MousePosition)){GameObject.Find("TheObject").GetComponent(thescriptwithoutthespeachmarks).enabled = true;}`
- By the way did you create a reference to the `GUITexture`?

Comment: Did you mean did I attach the script to the Gui Texture? Yes I did. I got the error saying No appropriate version of "UnityEngine.GUIElement.HitTest' for the argument list '(function(int): boolean) was found

Comment: Well if it is attached, replace all occurence `GUITexture` by `gameObject`.

Comment: I think its the problem with the HitTest thing

Comment: Retry with the `.Contains` and replace `GUITexture` by `gameObject`.

Comment: I did but still didn't work. Can I ask a question? Is unity script the same as unity's javascript? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Hmmmm... that's weird... I think the last resort is to add a `collider` to it, then the `onMouseOver(), .Contains(), .HitTest()` will "have to" work with it. - UnityScript is a modified version of Javascript which is also known as Unity's Javascript. Only the way to declare variable are different.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
  if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
    GameObject.Find("Objectname").GetComponent<Script>.enabled = true;
  }
```